# Check internet connection with offline.js

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins, offline, internet-connection

I am creating phonegap application for android.

I want to check internet connection for application. I am using offline.js.

But it's not working at all for me.

My code is,

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>datePickerAngularTPLS</title>
    <link href="css/offline.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="scripts/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/offline.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            function on(evt) {
                alert("connected successfully");
            }
            function off(evt) {
                alert("connection failed");
            }
            Offline.on("up", on);
            Offline.on("off", off);
        });
    </script>
    <!-- Cordova reference, this is added to your app when it's built. -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

What is the problem in above code... ?
I just want to show alert on success and lose of internet connection.

I have also tried with navigator.isOnlie, but not reliable.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow offline js [**LINK**](https://github.com/hubspot/offline)

Or other way is :

```
window.navigator.onLine
```

This will return true or false.

And one more way is using Phonegap available plugin:

[**Phonegap Plugin**](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_connection_connection.md.html)

Answer (score 0):

In your first example you have forgotten to close the `$` function.  Its likely you would see an error message in the console, and those handlers would never have been created/attached.

If this is just a typo in your question and you are properly closing that function in your *real* code, then my guess is that you're adding the handlers *after* the `up` event has already occurred.  [Here](http://github.hubspot.com/offline/#properties) it explains when these events are triggered.

If you load your page, then toggle your connection on and off do you see the events logged?

Comment: Please take a look on updated question... and suggest something...
Currently no alert message is coming.

Comment: Do you have any errors in your console?  And do you have a `/favicon.ico` available for `offlinejs` to test the connection?  Have a look [here](http://github.hubspot.com/offline/#checking)

Comment: Yes I have added favicon.ico image in project... and there is no error message on console too.